# Can't Get Payment to Go Through In the Last Week or So

Tags: appcenter

Basically, as above. Haven't been able to get an Appcenter purchase to go through in a bit now. Get the error attached. Used to work fine. Any ideas? Payment source definitely has enough money.

[image: Appcenter Payment Error]

Comment: I could pay for a couple of apps, and then since a few days ago it has stopped working. There is no issue with my banks and I tested with two credit cards, so I wonder what's going on.